# How to do clone stamp in flutter canvas?

Tags: flutter, canvas

Is it possible to to copy a a shape/paint from other position and paste it to other position? Its like the clone stamp tool in Photoshop.

I am able to draw the shape like below

```
    //drawing eyebrow frame
    Path leftEyePath = Path();
    leftEyePath.moveTo(leftEyebrow[0].getX(),leftEyebrow[0].getY()-20);//-20 to move upward to skin surface
    for(int i=1;i<leftEyebrow.length;i++){
      leftEyePath.lineTo(leftEyebrow[i].getX(),leftEyebrow[i].getY()-20);
    }
    canvas.drawPath(leftEyePath,_myPainter);
```

The output is as below

[image]

**How do I copy the paint from blue shape into the red shape to remove the eyebrow?**

Comment: This is possible..even I'm curious somebody should answer

Comment: I used to play with libgdx , the easiest solution might be playing around with blend mode , but it's hard to find learning material in flutter...

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/BlendMode-class.html

Comment: Have you checked it?

Comment: Yes I did , but I am curious if this can be done with layer , it has to be a rect shape. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/saveLayer.html

Comment: You can try clipping the path and drawing the image on canvas, result you'll get is exactly what's inside the blue path..did you get what I said?..it's possible!

Comment: And then use path.getBounds() to get the rect, and save the layer..it'll be rect but pixels outside the path will be transperent

Comment: that path.getBounds() do save me some times! I am about to convert the path to rect with math.

Comment: I'll post the answer later in the day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with **canvas.clipPath(path)** and altering the image position to draw the image at other location.

```
canvas.save();
canvas.clipPath(leftEyePath);
paintImage(
   canvas: canvas, 
   rect: Rect.fromLTWH(0,25, size.width, size.height),
   image: image
);
canvas.restore();
```